# Cannot get data using LINQ in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to get data in autocomplete from JsonResult Action Method in my controller. I cannot query data with LINQ, I'm sharing code please guide me.

Action Method

```
public class VehicleController : Controller
{
        private readonly IService<Vehicle> _service;

        public VehicleController(IService<Vehicle> service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }
    public JsonResult AutoComplete(string term)
    {
       var vehicle = _service.GetAll().Select(c => new { Name = c.Name });
       return Json(vehicle, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

EntityRepository

```
public class EntityRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    private readonly IEntitiesContext _context;
    private readonly IDbSet<TEntity> _dbEntitySet;
    private bool _disposed;

    public EntityRepository(IEntitiesContext context)
    {
       _context = context;
       _dbEntitySet = _context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public List<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
       return _dbEntitySet.ToList();
    }
}
```

IRepository

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
   List<TEntity> GetAll();
}
```

Service

```
public class Service<TEntity> : IService<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
   public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; private set; }
   private readonly IRepository<TEntity> _repository;
   private bool _disposed;

   public Service(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
   {
      UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
      _repository = UnitOfWork.Repository<TEntity>();
   }

   public List<TEntity> GetAll()
   {
      return _repository.GetAll();
   }
}
```

IService

```
public interface IService<TEntity> : IService where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    List<TEntity> GetAll();
}
```

Action Method is returning a complete list of data but when I apply any filter it won't work and returns no values -- e.g I tried this and it returns null:

```
var vehicle = _service.GetAll().Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith(term)).Select(c => new { Name = c.Name });
```

Comment: Sorry but where you pass `term` parameter from action to service method?

Comment: @Kamo it is an autocomplete, term is coming from UI and in service, how i can pass?

Comment: It's ok, now I see how you used it :) Are you sure `term` matches any result in your DB? Remember this comparison is case-sensitive(so 'm' doesn't match 'M')

Comment: @freedomn-m - I cannot agree - author uses `ToList()` method before `Where()` so further comparison is not the part of `LinqToSql`

Comment: You've not shown the View (first line would suffice).  Can you also show the code where it does work (with just Getall() is implied in the QA, but not clear)   `.GetAll()` returns a `Vehicle` enumeration, but `.GetAll().Where...Select(c=>new { Name... })` returns a `string` enumeration.

Comment: @Kamo yes, if i query "My" there are 40 matching records in my DB.

Comment: @freedomn-m UI is just based on simple textbox and jquery autocomplete, i even tried fetching json directly from URL but it return null or empty list

Comment: @Usama - have `service.GetAll()` alone returned anything?

Comment: Just checking as a lot of questions are solved because the return type changes between working / not working.

Comment: @kamo yes it is returning entity list

Comment: Ok - what are you passing as `term`?  "My*" ?

Comment: Well your text probably doesn't start with "My*", it starts with "My".    eg `My Documents` not `My* Documents`   `StartsWith()` doesn't use a wildcard.

Comment: Im not using wildcard im just passing text and it even don't work if i just pass raw string in startwith method parameter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80648/discussion-between-usama-and-freedomn-m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure `term` matches the case of the data.  As all the data is loaded (`.ToList()` in the DAL), the `.Where` clause uses .Net comparison rather than SQL comparison:

```
    var vehicle = _service.GetAll().Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith(term, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)...
```

If, in the future, you want to change this to `Contains`, you can add an extension method:

```
    public static bool Contains(this string source, string toCheck, StringComparison comp)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        return source.IndexOf(toCheck, comp) >= 0;
    }
```

then

```
    var vehicle = _service.GetAll().Where(c => c.Name.Contains(term, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)...
```

Comment: One more things, can i apply select in resultant list? currently it is returning all fields i just want to return only Name field, can i do this with this solution?\

Comment: Of course, now you've confirmed the issue, you can change the return type to just string and change the code that handles it to just string using the `Select` you had in the original question.